# Copy SQL Server rows to new rows based on Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. Assume I have a table structured like this (the below denotes the column names / types):

```
ID - Int (Primary Key) [This is set to autoincrement]
X - varchar(MAX)
Y - varchar(MAX)
Z - varchar(MAX)
```

I am trying to build a generic query that based on the a value of one of the columns, the query can copy the values of existing records into a new record, change some column values and naturally increment the ID. Consider the following pseudo code (I couldn't think of a way to distill this otherwise :/) :

1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE X = "Hello" 
INTO TEMPTABLE
```

2)

```
COPY RESULTS 
FROM TEMPTABLE 
INTO TABLE 
SET X = "HI HI HI" AND SET Y "HI!"
```

The expected result from the above would be the result set from 1) feeding the record creation in 2). The value of Z should be naturally copied over since we aren't setting it otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO foobar (x, y, z)
SELECT 'HI HI HI', 'HI!', z FROM foobar WHERE x = 'Hello'
```